# Array to String conversion error when using array_diff and ajax

Tags: php, sql, json, codeigniter

I have custom framework like CodeIgniter.
I use Ajax to get data from data base but I have this message: *"array to string conversion"*.

What is the reason and how I can  solve this echo?

***controller***

```
public function getallserials()
        {
            if(isset($_POST['action'],$_POST['notebook_id'],$_POST['resseler_id'],$_POST['pos_id'])&&$_POST['action']=="getserial")
            {
                $allNoteBookSerials=$this->loadModel("NotebookRessellerDetails")->retrieveAllData("where `deleted`=? and `notebook_id`=? and `id_resseller`=? ",array(1,$_POST['notebook_id'],$_POST['resseler_id']));
                $addedSerialToPos=$this->loadModel("PosNotebookSerialsModel")->retrieveAllData("where `deleted`=? and `notebook_id`=? and `resseler_id`=? ",array(1,$_POST['notebook_id'],$_POST['resseler_id']));
                if(is_array($addedSerialToPos))
                {
                    // get serials only
                    foreach ($addedSerialToPos as $key => $value):
                        $RegisterdSerials[$key] =$value['serial'];
                    endforeach;
                }

                if(is_array($allNoteBookSerials))
                {
                        if(is_array($allNoteBookSerials)&&is_array($RegisterdSerials))
                        {
                            //$x=array_values(array_diff($RegisterdSerials,$allNoteBookSerials)) ;
                            $x=array_diff($RegisterdSerials,$allNoteBookSerials) ;

                            $response['status']="success";
                            $response['x']=(isset($x))?$x:null;
                            echo    $this->loadAjax()->DataToJson($response);
                            exit();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

**My Ajax code**

```
$("body").on("change","#notebook_id",function () {
    var notebook_id=$(this).val()
    var pos_id=$("#pos_id").val();
    var resseler_id=$("#resseler_id").val();
    var action="getserial";
    // start ajax

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo BASE_URL.'PosNoteBookserials/getallserials' ?>",
        method:"post",
        data:{notebook_id:notebook_id,pos_id:pos_id,resseler_id:resseler_id,action:action},
        beforeSend:function(){
        },
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                alert( "page not found" );
            },
        },
        success:function (data) {
            /*
            var  text='';
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if(result['status']=="success")
                {

                    for (i=0;i<result['allNoteBookSerials'].length;i++)
                    {
                        text+='<label class="label label-success">'+result['allNoteBookSerials'][i]['serial']+'</label>';

                        $("#res").html(text);
                    }

                }else{

                }
                */
            /*
        */
            alert(data);
            var  text='';
            var result = JSON.parse(data);

            if(result['status']=="success")
            {


                for (i=0;i<result['x'].length;i++)
                {
                    text+='<label class=" label label-success">'+result['x'][i]+'</label>';

                    $("#res").html(text);
                }

            }else{

            }

        }
    })
```

When I send a request I get a response of x, with correct data as array but the error *"array to string conversion"* appears on the line that contains this code.

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: $x=array_diff($RegisterdSerials,$allNoteBookSerials) ;

Comment: What leads to say that `$x=array_diff($RegisterdSerials,$allNoteBookSerials) ; ` is the line where the error occurs?

Comment: yes this is the error

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getallserials()
    {
     if(isset($_POST['action'],$_POST['notebook_id'],$_POST['resseler_id'],$_POST['pos_id'])&&$_POST['action']=="getserial")
        {
            $allNoteBookSerials=$this->loadModel("NotebookRessellerDetails")->retrieveAllData("where `deleted`=? and `notebook_id`=? and `id_resseller`=? ",array(1,$_POST['notebook_id'],$_POST['resseler_id']));
            $addedSerialToPos=$this->loadModel("PosNotebookSerialsModel")->retrieveAllData("where `deleted`=? and `notebook_id`=? and `resseler_id`=? ",array(1,$_POST['notebook_id'],$_POST['resseler_id']));


            $RegisterdSerials=array();
            if(is_array($addedSerialToPos))
            {
                // get serials only
                foreach ($addedSerialToPos as $key => $value):
                    $RegisterdSerials[$key] =$value['serial'];
                endforeach;
            }

            if(is_array($allNoteBookSerials))
            {
                    if(is_array($allNoteBookSerials) && is_array($RegisterdSerials))
                    {
                        //$x=array_values(array_diff($RegisterdSerials,$allNoteBookSerials)) ;
                        $x=array_diff($RegisterdSerials,$allNoteBookSerials) ;

                        $response['status']="success";
                        $response['x']=(is_array($x))?$x:[];
                        echo  json_encode($response);
                        exit();
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, adding `$RegisterdSerials=array();` will not solve the problem.

Comment: $x=array_diff($RegisterdSerials,$allNoteBookSerials)